# One makefile to compile all the source in a specified directory

Tags: c++, makefile

I am currently working through a c++ textbook; I'd like to have separate folders for exercises in the book, and a single makefile in the root, so that in the root directory I can type

```
make directoryName
```

and it will compile all the sources in that directory, and output a binary into the root. Here is what I have so far:

```
FLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal
OUT=helloworld.out

%: $(wildcard $@/*.cpp) 
    g++ $@/$(wildcard *.cpp) -o $(OUT) $(FLAGS)
```

But when I try to run it, all I get is

```
pc-157-231:Section2$ make helloWorld
make: `helloWorld' is up to date.
```

Any help appreciated

**Edit**
Note; the problem is not that I haven't changed the target file; I did...

Comment: Change helloWorld and then use make file.. here was no change that is why the message is shown

Comment: I did change it, that isn't the problem

Comment: That is why it is saying the file is up to date. It will compile only when there is change..else it will not compile

Comment: I believe there should be a `tab` before `g++`.

Comment: @rubikonx9 Sorry that was my bad; it was there in the makefile I just didn't put it into SO right. Edited.

Comment: @Grv Make is wrong - there was a change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that automatic GNU make variables such as `$@` only have a value within the *body* of the rule. From GNU make documentation.

> [Automatic variables] cannot be accessed directly within the prerequisite list of a rule. A common mistake is attempting to use `$@` within the prerequisites list; this will not work. ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html))

Additonally, you do not need the `$(wildcard ...)` function in your rule (both in body and in prerequisite list), although it's not a mistake either:

> Wildcard expansion happens automatically in rules. ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html))

Comment: To be clear, what the OP wants is not possible, is that what you mean ?

Comment: @kebs at least not straightforward. I would not say "technically impossible" as GNU make + shell commands in the Makefile allow to build extremely complex make rules.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a replacement for make that makes this very easy, but it is otherwise very experimental / not-officially-supported etc. You can download it from https://github.com/dascandy/bob .

You would probably be able to write this as:

```
FLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal    

# Take all cpp files in a folder & compile it to executable with that folder name as name.
(.*)/.*\.cpp => \1.out
  g++ -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)
```

or alternatively, with intermediate objects (better for large projects, but probably useless for small exercises)

```
FLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -Wfloat-equal    

# Read as, compile any CPP file to a file with the same root but .o as extension
(.*)\.cpp => \1.o
  g++ -c -o $@ $^ $(FLAGS)

# read as, take all objects in a subfolder together and compile into executable with folder name as name.
(.*)/.*\.o => \1.out
  g++ -o $@ $^
```

The tool itself requires Boost.Filesystem to be installed.

If you want to have a default target that compiles all executables, add these lines:

```
.*.out => all
  echo -n
```

(the echo is because it expects all rules to have a command)